# Is there a rotation of the polarization plane in rotating refractive media?

Tags: special-relativity, polarization, rotation

Since there is a transverse [Fresnel–Fizeau effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau_experiment) according to

> Jones, R. V. (1972). ["'Fresnel Aether Drag' in a Transversely Moving Medium"](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1972.0081). Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 328 (1574): 337–352. Bibcode:1972RSPSA.328..337J. doi:10.1098/rspa.1972.0081.

and

> Jones, R. V. (1975). ["'Aether Drag' in a Transversely Moving Medium"](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1975.0141). Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 345 (1642): 351–364. Bibcode:1975RSPSA.345..351J. doi:10.1098/rspa.1975.0141.

described for a rotating cylinder of length t as

$$
\delta  = r \omega t (n - 1/n)/c 
$$

where $\delta$ is the transverse displacement, r radius and $\omega$ rotational speed,
one could imagine that there is a rotation of the polarization plane of electromagnetic waves as they pass through a rotating medium (parallel to the rotation axis). How can this effect be determined, in terms of refractive index n and rotation $\omega$ of the rotating medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [On the dragging of the plane of polarization of light propagating in a rotating medium](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1976.0083)
> Proc. R. Soc. London, Ser. A349, 423(1976),
> Author: M. A. Player

The rotation of the plane of polarization of light propagating along the axis of rotation of a rotating dielectric medium is $(1/n_ϕ) (n_g - 1/n_ϕ)$ (where $n_g$ and $n_ϕ$ are the group and phase refractive indices of the medium respectively), equal to that found for ‘aether drag’ in the transverse case.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is

> Miles Padgett, Graeme Whyte, John Girkin, Amanda Wright, Les Allen, Patrik Öhberg, and Stephen M. Barnett, "[Polarization and image rotation induced by a rotating dielectric rod: an optical angular momentum interpretation](https://doi.org/10.1364/OL.31.002205)," Opt. Lett. 31, 2205-2207 (2006)